# Error building react native app on Android

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-studio, gradle

Hi I´m trying to run my react native app on android but when i build it shows me this error:

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 952 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...
> Task :react-native-safe-area-context:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
48 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 46 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-safe-area-context:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not find tools.jar. Please check that /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home contains a valid JDK installation.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-safe-area-context:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not find tools.jar. Please check that /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home contains a valid JDK installation.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s

    at makeError (/Users/calebgarcia/Dev/Auth/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /Users/calebgarcia/Dev/Auth/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/Users/calebgarcia/Dev/Auth/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:106:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/calebgarcia/Dev/Auth/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:192:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

It´s a bit puzzling since when i build the app on the ios simulator it runs perfectly.

Do you guys have any idea how i can solve the issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install react-native-safe-area-context
```

Try this and build.

If not,

Please check your computer's environment variables and set JAVA_HOME if it has not already been setup.